# Change value of primary key before Inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables `component` and `page` have relation many-to-many, I want to Change the `Id` of the component before inserting in the table like this `records+1` with also extra string. My problem that creating item component works good but it doesn't create a record in the join table `componentPage`.

```
public virtual async Task<T> Add(T obj, string createdBy= null, bool IsAutogeneratedId = true)
{
    obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    obj.CreatedBy = createdBy;

    // Just for creating page, component and componentsUserRoles
    if (!IsAutogeneratedId)
    {
        var lastId = entities.Count();
        var appId = createdBy.Split("=");
        var newId = $"{appId[0].Replace(": ", "")}_{lastId + 1}";
        obj.Id = newId;
    }
    
    _context.Attach(obj).State = EntityState.Added;

    // await entities.AddAsync(obj);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return obj;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to attach the new Item that I want to create!

```
public virtual async Task<T> Add(T obj, string createdBy= null, bool IsAutogeneratedId = true)
        {
            obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            obj.CreatedBy = createdBy;

            if (_context.Entry(obj).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                entities.Attach(obj);
            }

            if (!IsAutogeneratedId)
            {
                var lastId = entities.Count();
                var appId = createdBy.Split("=");
                var newId = $"{appId[0].Replace(": ", "")}_{lastId + 1}";
                obj.Id = newId;
            }

            _context.Attach(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return obj;
        }
```